# id and anchor link inside url not scrolling to anchor

Tags: html

I need an id inside url and scroll to an anchor link

```
<a name="tags" id='tags'></a> 

<a href="edit.php?id=382#tags">GO</a>
```

also tried:

```
<a href="edit.php?id=382&#tags">GO</a>
```

Simply - doesn't work. Page is loaded on top or if reloaded - on current scroll position.

Just sometimes scrolling appears near to the `tags` anchor.

Any help?

Comment: it's little code to work with... anyway, any (unique) element holding the `id="tags"` attribute on the page should cause you to be scrolled over there

Comment: @giorgio, there is no another `class` or ` id` named `tags` on the page.

Comment: please post the relevent code; the full link you're clicking and the element you try to target

Comment: @giorgio I did.

Comment: just try `edit.php#tags`

Comment: @amansinghgusain, `edit.php#tags` - doesn't work, there is no scrolling at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is just fine. But there has to be enough scrollable height in your page. 
 Below example works.

```
<a href="index.html?id=382&#link1">GO To Link 1</a> <!-- redirect to link 1 -->

<a href="index.html?id=382#link2">GO To Link 2</a> <!-- redirect to link 2 -->

<div style="height:100%;"></div>

<a name="tags" id='link1'>Link 1</a> <!-- link 1 -->

<div style="height:100%;"></div>

<a name="tags" id='link2'>Link 2</a> <!-- link 2 -->

<div style="height:100%;"></div>
```